# How to set the visual constraints for a new view, and make it match the frame dimensions of its new parent?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

does someone see something wrong with this visual constraint?

I try to add a view programmatically when we select a row in a tableView. (the view is `600x600` in `wAny/hAny`, and it should match the new frame of its new parent when I add it to my ViewController: I try on an iphone5, the width now becomes `320`)

I added a *red button* on the right side of this view (`trailing/top/width/height`). Then in my `viewController`, the width is 320, so the red button should still be visible on the right side because of the trailing constraint.
I tried with the frame, or with constraints but the view does not change its frame, the red button is still offscreen.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if currentIndexPath == indexPath.row {
            //pritnln("\(detailView.frame)")
            detailView.frame = CGRectMake(0, tableView.frame.origin.y+44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

            let v : Dictionary<String,UIView> = ["detailView":detailView]
            let heightSpace : Dictionary<String, CGFloat> = ["heightSpace":tableView.frame.origin.y+44]

            self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[detailView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: v))
            self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-heightSpace-[detailView]|", options: nil, metrics: heightSpace, views: v))

            detailView.hidden = false
        }
```

The log is :

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try
>   this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it.

---

EDIT:

```
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-heightSpace-[detailView]|", options: nil, metrics: heightSpace, views: v))


--> [detailView]|



(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1556eeb0 h=--& v=--& MyProject.DetailView:0x15566fa0.midX ==>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1556ee40 h=--& v=--& H:[MyProject.DetailView:0x15566fa0(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1556f350 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x15670400(320)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1556f3b0 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x15670400]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x155465e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1554e640 H:[MyProject.DetailView:0x15566fa0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x15670400 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1554e640 H:[MyProject.DetailView:0x15566fa0]-(0)-|
```

The second attempt :

```
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-heightSpace-[detailView]-|", options: nil, metrics: heightSpace, views: v))


--> [detailView]-|


(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1464d860 h=--& v=--& MyProject.DetailView:0x1455e650.midY ==>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1464d890 h=--& v=--& V:[MyProject.DetailView:0x1455e650(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14656950 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x146475d0(568)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x146569b0 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x146475d0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14636f20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14545010 UIView:0x146475d0.bottomMargin == MyProject.DetailView:0x1455e650.bottom>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14545010 UIView:0x146475d0.bottomMargin == MyProject.DetailView:0x1455e650.bottom>
```

Thanks

Comment: Which constraint does the log say it's breaking?

Comment: like Dreaming In Binary said, it would help, to know what constraint is being broken. If you can't easily see it, add a symbolic breakpoint to catch it. (the symbol should be in the error log you're seeing)

Comment: Tipp: don't set frames if using auto layout. Change frames with constraints.

Comment: @DreamingInBinary OK I start to see where the problem is, but I haven't fix it yet :) I edited my post.

Comment: @iOSfleer same message as above :) I edited my post.